# Rails Rabl gem: query child based on parent id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rabl

The rails method:

```
def index
 user = Users.find(params[:user_id])
 @countries = user.countries
 @cities = user.cities
end
```

Country model has_many :cities

City model belongs_to :country

User has access to certain countries and certain cities

The corresponding json.rabl file:

```
object false
child @countries do 
 child @cities.where(country_name: country.name) do
  attributes :name, :coordinates
 end
end
```

My question is about `child @cities.where(country_name: country.name)`

My goal is to filter the @cities to only include the cities for the current parent country.

Is this possible in rabl?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an instance variable for `@cities`, you can use an association on your Country model.

The one question I would have, is this the index method for the User?

Something like this may work:

```
object @user
child :countries do
  child :cities do
    attributes :name, :coordinates
  end
end
```